# 2d interpolation minimizing the integral of the norm of the Hessian

Tags: linear-algebra, random-walks, brownian-motion, interpolation, bayesian-probability

It is well known that cubic interpolation is the solution of the interpolation problem that minimizes the integral of the square of the second derivative:
$$ min_{f \text{ s.t. } f(x_i)=y_i} \int (f''(x))^2 dx $$

I would like to know what is the corresponding scheme in dimension 2.
In other terms, what is the solution of the minimization of
$$ min_{f \text{ s.t. } f(x_i)=y_i} \int \|\text{Hessian}(f)\|^2 dx $$
where $(x_i)$ are points in 2d and y_i real numbers.

Is there a known efficient method in the case of an equidistant grid?

I would also be interested in Bayesian interpretations of those methods: splines are maximum likelihood if we assume a Brownian motion prior for the derivative. What is the equivalent in dimension 2?

Comment: I think a generalization closer to the 1D case would be with something like $(f''_{xx})^2+(f''_{yy})^2+2(f''_{xy})^2$ instead of $|\text{Hessian}(f)|^2$.

Comment: agreed, the Frobenius norm is probably what we want.